# Store concrete structs that implement a trait with type placeholders in a HashMap

Tags: rust, traits

So I'd like to have a registry for instances of structs that all implement a certain trait.
The problem is that the trait defines type placeholders `type Inputs` and `type Outputs`.

The trait looks like this:

```rust
trait Block {
    type Inputs;
    type Outputs;
    
    fn do_something(&self, inputs: &Self::Inputs) -> Result<Self::Outputs>;
}
```

All structs that implement the trait define a concrete type for the `Inputs` and `Outputs`.

```rust
impl Block for FirstBlock {
    type Inputs = FirstInputs;
    type Outputs = FirstOutputs;

    fn do_something(&self, inputs: &Self::Inputs) -> Result<Self::Outputs> {
        Ok(FirstOutputs { count: inputs.num + inputs.num })
    }
}
```

I made a small example on the Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab7f365253fc74b789d4f6b9520603e0

I made enums (`BlockInputs` and `BlockOutputs`) for all types that can occur as `Inputs` and `Outputs` and made an `impl Into<BlockInputs>` for them in the hope that something like this would work:

```rust
let mut registry: HashMap<String, Box<dyn Block<Inputs = dyn Into<BlockInputs>, Outputs = dyn Into<BlockOutputs>>>> = HashMap::new();
```

But it obviously won't since `Into` is a trait.

Any idea on how I could store the structs that implement the `Block` trait from the example?

Comment: Let's suppose one retrieves an element from this `registry`, and then wishes to call its `do_something` method.  Since we don't know its concrete type or its concrete `Inputs` associated type, we cannot know what type must be provided for that method call's `inputs` argument; likewise what the return type will be.  Instead, we must surely pass an instance of your `BlockInputs` enum and be returned an instance of your `BlockOutputs` enum.  This suggests the solution: remove the associated types, and use the enums in the method signatures instead.

Comment: So I resolved the issue by removing the `BlockInputs` and `BlockOutputs` enums, maintaining the concrete types for the `Inputs` and `Outputs` placeholders and wrapping all structs in an enum. [final result here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb35ee2c5701f650a91bfe0e50f0b243)

Comment: That's fine if the set of `BlockTypes` is closed.  That you were using trait objects previously had suggested that the set was instead open (eg that further implementations might be defined downstream).